# test.txt to COSM or MySQL to COSM Possible

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, cosm

Good Evening All,

A friend of mine is using COSM via API commands from his Arduino GPRS module. However mine is Arduino to PC using XBEE, stored in MySQL via text document and viewed on HTML. Is it possible, anywhere along this process, to upload my most recent data to COSM?

Just wanted to see if anyone knows of it before i continue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to send the data to Cosm at the same point at which you insert it into MySQL. I assume this is some kind of script listening on the serial port, so you should just be able to add it in there somewhere.